# Validate GridView edit row based on SQL results

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Fairly new to coding here.  I have a GridView where users enter staff based on a username TextBox.  It uses a method GetUserInfo to do a SQL query and autofill the rest of the TextBox columns when users create or edit a row.  If no rows are found by SQL, I want an error message to appear and the GridView to not accept the row.  Essentially validation on the username field.

I must do everything programmatically (constraint of the 3rd party WorkflowGen software).  I can list the details of the hokey things I've tried, but I feel like I'm missing the best approach here.  How do I mix a Validator (if I need one), the results of the SQL query, a client side "invalid" message, and denial of row update if invalid?  I'm getting confused by too many moving parts and the page life cycle, I think.

```
<asp:GridView id="COLLAB_GRIDVIEW" showheader="True" showfooter="True" runat="server" autogeneratecolumns="false" onrowdatabound="GridView_RowDataBound">
<Columns><asp:TemplateField><EditItemTemplate><asp:TextBox autopostback="true" ontextchanged="GetUserInfo" value="" id="COLLAB_GRIDVIEW_INTERNET_ID" text="<%# Bind('COLLAB_GRIDVIEW_INTERNET_ID') %>" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></EditItemTemplate><ItemTemplate><asp:Label id="COLLAB_GRIDVIEW_INTERNET_ID" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("COLLAB_GRIDVIEW_INTERNET_ID") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField><EditItemTemplate><asp:TextBox id="COLLAB_GRIDVIEW_FIRST_NAME" text="<%# Bind('COLLAB_GRIDVIEW_FIRST_NAME') %>" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></EditItemTemplate><ItemTemplate><asp:Label id="COLLAB_GRIDVIEW_FIRST_NAME" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("COLLAB_GRIDVIEW_FIRST_NAME") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField><EditItemTemplate><asp:TextBox value="" id="COLLAB_GRIDVIEW_LAST_NAME" text="<%# Bind('COLLAB_GRIDVIEW_LAST_NAME') %>" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></EditItemTemplate><ItemTemplate><asp:Label id="COLLAB_GRIDVIEW_LAST_NAME" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("COLLAB_GRIDVIEW_LAST_NAME") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField><EditItemTemplate><asp:TextBox value="" id="COLLAB_GRIDVIEW_DEPT_NAME" text="<%# Bind('COLLAB_GRIDVIEW_DEPT_NAME') %>" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></EditItemTemplate><ItemTemplate><asp:Label id="COLLAB_GRIDVIEW_DEPT_NAME" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("COLLAB_GRIDVIEW_DEPT_NAME") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField><EditItemTemplate><asp:TextBox value="" id="COLLAB_GRIDVIEW_COLLEGE" text="<%# Bind('COLLAB_GRIDVIEW_COLLEGE') %>" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></EditItemTemplate><ItemTemplate><asp:Label id="COLLAB_GRIDVIEW_COLLEGE" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("COLLAB_GRIDVIEW_COLLEGE") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField><EditItemTemplate><asp:TextBox id="COLLAB_GRIDVIEW_CAMPUS" text="<%# Bind('COLLAB_GRIDVIEW_CAMPUS') %>" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></EditItemTemplate><ItemTemplate><asp:Label id="COLLAB_GRIDVIEW_CAMPUS" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("COLLAB_GRIDVIEW_CAMPUS") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:CommandField buttontype="Button" showdeletebutton="True" showeditbutton="True" causesvalidation="False" insertvisible="False"></asp:CommandField>
</Columns>
```

```
private void GetCollabInfo(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox sdr= (TextBox)sender;
    string internetid = sdr.Text.ToString();

    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)sdr.NamingContainer;
    int rowIndex = row.RowIndex;

    string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Datasource_IGM"].ConnectionString;
    string sql = "SELECT DISTINCT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, PRIMARY_DEPTID_DESCR, UM_RRC_DESCR, CAMPUS_DESCR FROM IGM.PRIMARY_JOB_WITH_TENURE WHERE INTERNET_ID = '" + internetid + "'";

    DataTable dtDemo = SelectStatement(conn, sql);

    if (dtDemo != null && dtDemo.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        ((TextBox)row.Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text = dtDemo.Rows[0]["FIRST_NAME"].ToString();
    // etc for the rest of the columns
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the **Behavior** of the columns of the GridView to **Required**. The error messages will be automatically generated and ready to be triggered whenever one of the fields is empty.

You can set them using the **Behavior** functionality in the form designer.
Or by modifying the action parameter "FORM_FIELD_REQUIRED" and adding the ID of the GridView fields desired.